# alert text & variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, alert, var

Can I put both text and variable in the same alert box
I thought the code down would work but it didn't

```js
alert('text'Variable);
```

Comment: Where is `Total` defined? Please share your full code.

Comment: It WOULD work if you had defined Total somewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
alert('Your text goes here'+your var goes here);
```

I find out the code I should have put

Answer (score 8):

```js
var name = "John Doe";

function myFunction() {
  alert('Hello ' + name);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Checkout</button>
```