# How to add space in the Alert() comments

Tags: javascript

How can I add space in my alert. In my last code, it always display I don't know that car(variable). I want a space between variable and car.

thank you!

```
var car=prompt("what type of car you like");

switch(car){
case "ferari":
    document.write("italian stalion hey?");
case "porsche":
    break;
    document.write("german precision, i like that!")
case "dodge":
    break;
    document.write("American cars!");
    break;
default: 
    alert("i don't know that car"+car);
}
```

Comment: ... Put in a space?

Comment: `alert("i don't know that car "+car);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [alert text & variable JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947598/alert-text-variable-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you just have to add a space:

```
alert("i don't know that car " + car);
// This --------------------^
```

You are concatenating a variable with a string. To get that additional space, you simply have to add it.

Additionally, if you use [ES2015](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/) you can use template strings:

```
alert(`i don't know that car ${car}`);
//    ^--- Notice the backticks ---^
```

---

```js
var car = prompt("what type of car you like");

switch (car) {
  case "ferari":
    document.write("italian stalion hey?");
  case "porsche":
    break;
    document.write("german precision, i like that!")
  case "dodge":
    break;
    document.write("American cars!");
    break;
  default:
    alert("i don't know that car " + car);
}
```